# Neo4jError: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I am trying to create a db (neo4j) connection and run a basic query to create a node.
But it does not seem to work
I am getting error  . Here is the output

```
START
FINISH
error :  Neo4jError: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
```

Code is below

```
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
// const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')

let dbAddress = "bolt://localhost:7687"
let userName = "neo4j"
let password = "My Password"
let driver = neo4j.driver(
    dbAddress,
    neo4j.auth.basic(userName, password));

console.log("START");
let session = driver.session();
// let query = "match (n) return n"
session
    .run("CREATE (a:Person {name: ashish}) RETURN a")
    .then(
        result => {
            session.close()
            console.log("success")
            driver.close()
        },
        error => {
            session.close()
            let e = error.toString();
            console.log("error :  " + e)
            driver.close()
        }
    )
console.log("FINISH");
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as advised from the great Michael Hunger from Neo4J. Make sure you use the right driver and the right connection string.
typically the latest driver wouldn't use v1 in

> const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

I would recommend looking at this https://neo4j.com/docs/migration-guide/4.0/upgrade-driver/